# Android Studio gradle access denied after libgdx installation

Tags: java, android, gradle, libgdx

I work with Android Studio on 2 devices (one is fully operational with network connection; another has some protection put on, network is restricted, etc.) and the simplest way to do so was to install AS on external drive and then replug it to the device I need to use at the time. It is not perfect solution, but only which works (we'll get to that later). I have done installation on first PC and it works fine. After repluging to another device everything worked fine as well.
Some time later I decided to go with libgdx project. In the same time I have also updated some SDK stuff. Everything works fine on first device, but it doesn't on the second. I get error: "Received fatal alert: access_denied". So I have gone to offline mode (never needed to use it) but it lead me to another error:

> Error:Could not download gwt-gradle-plugin.jar
>   (de.richsource.gradle.plugins:gwt-gradle-plugin:0.6): No cached
>   version available for offline mode

For the first I thought it makes sense - gradle needs to sync (in online mode) and can't because of network restrictions. Then in offline it cannot work because of lack of cache files. So what I did is to copy .gradle folder from first PC to second and try again, but failed with the same errors.
Later I thought - maybe .gradle folder location is restricted (admin rights or so) and I have changed AS settings to use the folder on the external drive (temp copy) - still didn't solve it...

What might be the solution here? And before I get answers I need to mention - second PC can't be connected to not restricted network in any way so solution has to be done purely with AS or folders.

Answer (score 0):

Uncheck "Offline work" in Android Studio.

File --> Settings --> Gradle --> Global Gradle Settings

Edit: It could also be at:

File --> Settings --> Build, Execution, Deployment --> Build tools --> Gradle

Comment: How would that help if I already mentioned error I get in such case (access_denied)?

Comment: I thought it was obvious. Yes, I tried - I get access denied error.